# Nearest thing to windows 7 paint to run on XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-paint

I have used the paint program that comes with windows 7 and found it very useful - **especially the numerous predefined shapes**. Can I get that version of paint - or something very similar, for my windows-XP machine? I don't want anything too powerful that will require a lot of time to learn.

EDIT: Paint.NET may be a very good at what it does, but its a complete fail with regard what I actually need. I want to be able to draw a variety of shapes like arrows and stars for example.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Paint.Net](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/15260-plugin-index/)

Edit: [plugins for Paint.net](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/15260-plugin-index/), "random shape fill" plugin may fill your needs

Comment: I just downloaded it - I can't see many predefined shapes - am I missing something?

Comment: Inkscape? Vector Graphics

Comment: Gimp and Paint.Net are the 2 biggest replacement recommendations for W7 paint on the internet, try Google I suppose.

Comment: Mick, check my edit above.

Comment: "random shape fill" may sound correct - but its actually just a way of creating pretty backgrounds - its not a useful drawing tool.

Comment: Did you browse the hundreds of other plug ins?

Comment: @Moab - I had a look - but noticed that almost all the plugins appeared to be "effects" that could be applied to the whole image. I could scarcely see anything that corresponded to "drawing something".

Comment: @ Mick, I would make a post on the Paint.Net forums...http://forums.getpaint.net/

Comment: There are a lot of predefined shapes in Paint.Net by default, stars, arrows, rounded rectangles... First, select the _Shapes_ tool, then select a shape from the _Shapetype_ dropdown. No need to install any plugin for that. Lines can be drawn using the _Line/curve_ tool

Answer (score 3):

If you want an application that looks and functions like Windows 7 paint, try [PaintRibbon](http://www.bluuur.com/paintribbon).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) - Free Software for Digital Photo Editing

Alternatively you can use paintribbon, its a paint application for XP and Vista which has the ribbon and is made to look like the Windows 7 Paint. Check it out [here](http://www.bluuur.com/paintribbon)